# Razor - How to display html content in a div tag?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is my razor code:

```
       <fieldset>
            <legend>Headline News</legend>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Description)</div>
                }
        </fieldset>
```

The value for `item.Description` is HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;"><tr><td width="80" align="center" valign="top">
   {{ table info }}
</table>
```

I actually want to display the HTML content, but it shows up as HTML tags.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@Html.Raw(item.Description)</div>
}
```

Comment: However, the correct syntax that worked for me is:  <div>@Html.Raw(item.Description) </div>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@Html.Raw()`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => @Html.Raw(item.Description))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use `@Html.Raw`, unless there are some HTML tags that need to be parsed as HTML. You can also use

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Headline News</legend>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div>@item.Description</div>
}
</fieldset>
```

If you want to use `@Html.Raw`, just be sure on using `@Html.AttributeEncode` to prevent scripting injection

Comment: How to use @Html.AttributeEncode ? Also, <div>@item.Description</div> gives me syntax error.